# UPDATE Query : Incorrect Syntax

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I have a button in my windows forms which UPDATES every table. However, I am getting error SQLException was unhandled. Incorrect syntax near '='.

This is my code in Update Button:

```
  public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
    try
    {

     //MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString());
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
      new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=Test\\Test; Integrated Security=true; Database=Testing;");

     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET ShipTrackingNumber = '" + row.Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET ShipMethodTransmitted = '" + row.Cells[8].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET DateShipTransmitProcessed = '" + row.Cells[9].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET ShipmentProcessedBy = '" + row.Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET Critical = '" + row.Cells[11].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus SET ShipTransmitStatus = '" + row.Cells[13].FormattedValue.ToString() + "' WHERE jobtableid = " + row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString();

     cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

     sqlConnection1.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Update Failed!!!");
    }

   }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these statements? Thanks!

Comment: That code will only update ShipTranmitStatus; because you are replacing the CommandText on each line with new CommandText. You can update all the fields in 1 UPDATE statement instead of 6 separate ones. Also you should use SQLParameters to supply the values to your Command.

Comment: Also, are row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString() column names? if not, they will need to be wrapped in single quotes like the first block was.

Comment: @guildsbounty: even if jobtableid is an int?

Comment: So I should write my all UPDATE STATEMENT ALL IN ONE LINE?

Comment: In that case, no. And what you could do is, instead of running them like that. change your initial "=" to a "+=" that way you are appending to the CommandText, not overwriting it. Just make sure to also put in a semi-colon and an extra space at the end of each statement to keep them divided.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply do it in a single update statement. So something like:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine( "UPDATE dbo.JobStatus" );
sql.AppendLine( "Set ShipTrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber" );
sql.AppendLine( ", DateShipTransmitProcessed = @DateShipTransmitProcessed" );
sql.AppendLine( ", ShipmentProcessedBy = @ShipmentProcessedBy" );
sql.AppendLine( ", Critical = @Critical" );
sql.AppendLine( ", ShipTransmitStatus = @ShipTransmitStatus" );
sql.AppendLine( "Where jobtableId = @jobTableId" );

cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingNumber", row.Cells[7].FormattedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateShipTransmitProcessed", row.Cells[8].FormattedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipmentProcessedBy", row.Cells[9].FormattedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Critical", row.Cells[10].FormattedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipTransmitStatus", row.Cells[11].FormattedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobTableId", row.Cells[5].FormattedValue);
```

Comment: This is what I am getting error: UPDATE dbo.JobStatus
Set ShipTrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber
, DateShipTransmitProcessed = @DateShipTransmitProcessed
, ShipmentProcessedBy = @ShipmentProcessedBy
, Critical = @Critical
, ShipTransmitStatus = @ShipTransmitStatus
Where jobtableId = @jobTableId

Comment: @Mayank - What is the error or behavior you are encountering? "It's not working" provides no information I can use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what was mentioned in my comment; I don't see anything wrong with the syntax of your SQL. It's quite possible that your FormattedValue has an invalid character like a ' in the string itself, which would lead to a SQL error. Print out the value of the CommandText itself after the string has been built to see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your conditions thus:

```
if(row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString())
then execute update query
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `UPDATE` statement is incorrect. `UPDATE` syntax is:

   ```
   UPDATE table
      SET
         column1 = 'value',
         column2 = 'value2'
      WHERE
         condition;
   ```
2. You are overwriting your statement every time you assign to `cmd`. You probably want something more like:

   ```
   cmd =  "UPDATE table";
   cmd += "SET column1 = '" + value + "',";
   cmd += "SET column2 = " + intValue;
   cmd += "WHERE idRow = '" + rowToUpdateValue + "'";
   ```

Also, if this doesn't help, check that you are not trying to check an INT column using a 'char' value.